# Return customized validation error message in json format inside controller

Tags: json, cakephp, httpresponse

I am using Cakephp 2.4.5.

I have a controller which takes in an id and checks whether this id exists inside the Model. If it does not exist, I would like the controller to return a validation error message "id not found" in json when it returns the HTTP response. This controller takes in a normal HTTP POST which is not in json.

How can this be done in Cakephp 2.4.5?

My controller code looks something like this;

```
public function controller_function($id=null)
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
       $field=$this->request->data['Model']['field'];
       $Model_id = $this->Model->findFieldID($field);
       if (empty($Model_id) ) //record not found. Return validation error
       {
           //Send validation error back in JSON. How??
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('error_message' => 'id not found'));
```

And for the other stuff you are having problem, since you said there is no view, add this to your method:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. But I still have a problem. When I look at the HTTP response, it is full of other HTML code besides the json message. How can I remove the other HTML code and leave behind only a clean json message?

Comment: What other HTML code? Something is clearly outputting it somewhere.

Comment: It comes from cakephp. This is a API controller function with no corresponding form. Do I have to put in some dummy view file inside the view folder?

Comment: Thanks. It looks much better now.
I still get some error message like this;
`Notice (8): Undefined offset: 0 [APP\\Model\\Model1.php, line 23]` Are those cakephp debug messages? Can I remove them by setting the debug level down?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49646/discussion-between-skywalker-and-user3293156)